# How to convert date to this(yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ) format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

Im trying to convert date into yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ format but am enable to get it,
the scripting code am using is

```
var dateForUrl = new Date();
currentDate1=dateForUrl.toISOString();
```

this thing is converting the date but not in exact format as i want,it converts date as like `2016-09-25T13:00:00.000Z` where am expecting date like `2016-09-25T13:00:00:00Z`,i also tried

```
var dateInURL = new Date();
dateInURL = moment(dateInURL,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZZ").toDate();
```

it returns date as like

Sun sep 25 2016  00:00:00 gmt+0530  (india standard time)

so how can i get the date in `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ format`

Comment: but am used this .toISOString and tnothing came out

Comment: `.toUTCString();` try.

Comment: @KiRa
var date = new Date();
var date = date.toUTCString();
result-Sat, 24 Sep 2016 18:30:00 GMT

Comment: @Jaromanda X,i want to return date in 2016-09-25T13:00:00:00Z format

Comment: i thing i didn't mentioned xxZ anywhere

Comment: my answer below gives you what you want - despite you on two occasions requesting something different - I'm done, and about to delete the answer

Comment: @Ma6139735 did you already solve it?

Comment: no i didn'r and am enable to, that's why i posted question here

Comment: your code doesn't really format your date, if you try moment(dateInURL).toDate(); would still the same. that's not how format format a date. sorry for to much edit

Answer (score 1):

use moment format function to format your date to your desired date format

```
moment(dateInURL).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ");
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var d = new Date();
document.write(d.getFullYear()+ "-" + ("00" + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +("00" + d.getDate()).slice(-2)+" "+ ("00" + d.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":" +("00" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + ("00" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2));
```